# AttributeError: module 'keras.backend.tensorflow_backend' has no attribute 'set_image_dim_ordering'

Tags: python, keras

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-1f6cde7dea50> in <module>
      5 from keras.utils import np_utils
      6 from keras import backend as K
----> 7 K.tensorflow_backend.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
      8 import numpy as np
      9 import os

AttributeError: module 'keras.backend.tensorflow_backend' has no attribute 'set_image_dim_ordering'
```

I'm using keras version 2.3.1.

I am aware of a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851895/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-keras-api-v2-keras-backend-has-no-at) about this problem, but the original post's problem was caused by mixing tensorflow and keras in the importing section. However, I didn't use tensorflow in my program.

Comment: What happens when you try `K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')`?

Comment: @AloneTogether
It returns this error. 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-57420e561e59> in <module>
      5 from keras.utils import np_utils
      6 from keras import backend as K
----> 7 K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
      8 import numpy as np
      9 import os

AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'set_image_dim_ordering'

Comment: Interesting, which tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: @AloneTogether 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
from keras import backend as K
```

Use:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
```

Or keep it the same and use:

```
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```

Or use:

```
pip3 uninstall keras
pip3 install keras --upgrade
```

Comment: It returns this error


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-57420e561e59> in <module>
      5 from keras.utils import np_utils
      6 from keras import backend as K
----> 7 K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
      8 import numpy as np
      9 import os

AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'set_image_dim_ordering'

Comment: @Morgenstern Then try changing to `import tensorflow.keras.backend as K`

Comment: that returns the same attribute error

Comment: @Morgenstern Use `import tensorflow.keras.backend as K`, and `K.tensorflow_backend.set_image_dim_ordering('th')`

Comment: That returns the same attribute error as well. Could it be some problems with my keras installment or environment?

Comment: I tried reinstalling almost the entire environment, as well as on my friend's computer, neither worked